# Linear Gradient for Links

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give the link underline a linear gradient like shown below.

Unfortunately it doesn't display the colors here. Problem is that in my Browser I just see one color, the first one of the gradient … What's the problem for the second one? Wrong approach to make this underline gradient?

```css
a {  
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(57, 72, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(57,     213, 255, 1) 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 4px 4px;
    background-position: 0 22px;
  }
  
  a:visited {  color: #2a2a2a;
}
```

```html
<a href=""> <p> Lorem Ipsum </p> </a>
```

Ok, figured it out. If anyone else wondering what is the issue: You have to set the background size to `auto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
a {  
    background: linear-gradient(to right, 
    rgba(57, 72, 255, 1), 
    rgba(57, 213, 255, 1)
    );
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: 100% 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#">  Lorem Ipsum  </a>
```

- width of background have to by 100% width,
- positioned on bottom,
- and no-repeat.

On top of that i was removed default  underline.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this simple trick to set up gradient line to give the link underline a linear gradient like shown below

**CSS**

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #a0a0a0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 3px 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#a859ff,#6d0cc5 ,#3422c5,#0043ff,#0a6bfd,#00c4ff,#14e9ff);
  background-size: 100% 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: bottom;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#">Gradient Link</a>
```